# Creating an Admin view w/ CRUD operations for Devise Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, view, admin

I'm using Rails 4 w/ Devise for the first time and trying to build a view for Admins to lookup users and modify user attributes. Consequently, I've created a new boolean attribute, 'admin', to my Devise User model. However, this question is primarily concerned with building the admin view so the admin has CRUD operations that can be used on the different users.

In testing the 'show' view, I get the following error when trying to show a particular user's email address:

> 'undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass'

My admins_controller looks like this:

```
 class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

The corresponding 'index' and 'show' views look like this:

'views/admins/index.html.erb'

```
    <h1>Listing users</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Admin</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Zipcode</th>
  </tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.admin %></td>
    <td><%= user.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= user.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= user.address %></td>
    <td><%= user.city %></td>
    <td><%= user.state %></td>
    <td><%= user.zip %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
  </tr>s
<% end %>
</table>
```

'views/admins/show.html.erb'

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @users.email %>
</p>
```

Does anyone have thoughts as to what is causing the error?

Comment: What's your routes look like? You may also use activeadmin for admin stuff, it's compatible with devise.

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely check out activeadmin. Concerning the routes, they look like this:  resources :exams

  devise_for :users
  
  resources :admins

Comment: Since it's using 'index' as the params[:id], and your routes looks normal. You might have input something like `/admins/index` into browser url, try `/admins/1` instead, if you do have a user with a id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `resources admins` in your route, the `#index` action is actually `/admins/` no index needed. So when you do `/admins/index`, it's actually thinking you want go to `show` action with `index` mapped to `params[:id]`. You could use `rake routes` to see all your generated routes.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. So, how do I display all of the users via the '/admins/' route? When performing a GET via the browser to '/admins/' I get the following error 'undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8d1bb4cc38>:0x007f8d1cba9360>'. It doesn't seem to like '<td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>' in the admin's index view.

Comment: What you are asking `admins/1` for is actually using `admin_path(id: user.id)`. Since you used `resources admins` to generate a list of paths, including `GET admins/:id`, again, this could be looked at using `rake routes` the first column is how you write your routes, the last column is which controller and action it will be mapped into.

Comment: Anyway, your routes is not very idiomatic and semantic when what you are trying to do is `manage user with :id=1` and ended up with `admins/1`. You could use `:namespace` to isolate your admin controllers. You may look at the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing). :)

Comment: Thank you! Extremely helpful. I'm switching back to using a 'users' controller and ensuring only an a user who is an admin is able to access the views. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. It was a pleasure.